# Data is not saving properly as a nested JSON array in Nestjs MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nestjs

I am trying to add nested JSON array data inside mongodb database as I am using mongoose ORM but data is not saving as expected.Here why members are not saving in proper JSON array format its saving as a string that can be seen in postman below.

This is how I am passing the request body:
[image]

Below is my code:

**team.schema.ts**

```
import { Prop, Schema, SchemaFactory } from "@nestjs/mongoose";

export type TeamDocument = Team & Document;

@Schema({_id:false})
export class Member{

  @Prop()
  name:String;

  @Prop()
  age:Number;
}

export const MemberSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Member);

@Schema()
export class Team{

  @Prop()
  country:String;

  @Prop()
  members:[Member]; 
}

export const TeamSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(Team);
```

**team.dto.ts**

```
export class MemberDto{
 name:string;
 age:number;
}

export class TeamDto{
 country:string;
 members:MemberDto[];
}
```

**team.controller.ts**

```
import { Body, Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TeamDto } from './dto/team.dto';
import { TeamService } from './team.service';

@Controller()
export class TeamController {
 constructor(private teamService:TeamService){}

@Post('createTeam')
createTeam(@Body() teamDto:TeamDto){
    return this.teamService.createTeam(teamDto);       
  }
}
```

**team.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';
import { TeamDto } from './dto/team.dto';
import { Team } from './schema/team.schema';
import { Model} from 'mongoose';

@Injectable()
export class TeamService {
 constructor(@InjectModel('Teams') private teamModel:Model<Team>){}

 async createTeam(teamDto:TeamDto){
  
     const data = new this.teamModel(teamDto);
     const dat = await data.save();
     return dat;
  }
}
```

Someone let me know how can I add data in proper format any help would be appreciated.